# Center scroll bar on lower resolutions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My website's width is 1200px, when someone with lower resolution looking site horizontal scroll is visible and scroll bar is located to the left.

Is there way to locate scroll to center using css, javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use `$(window).scrollLeft();`

Just place the center value of the window into the scrollLeft function and the page will reposition itself. The easiest way to find the center of the page is to take your 1200 width and divide it by 2, then subtract the calculated `$(window).width();` divided by 2.

```
var scrollPos = (1200/2) - ($(window).width()/2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jquery for that. that is a basic thing for javascript.

`document.body.scrollLeft = (1200-window.innerWidth)/2`